# Erosion not working correct

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I tried to implement the erosion (morphological operation) in c++ and I used OpenCV for read and show the first image and image after erosion.

I want to explain step by step how I did:

1. I created my "binary image" (I used just black and white) using a matrix with random value of 255 or 0.
2. I copied the initial image into final image
3. Then I went through the matrix (final image) with a 3x3 mask and I counted if I have 9 value of 255.

My mask like:

```
[255 255 255
255 255 255
255 255 255]
```

4. If my counter is = 9, I colored the pixels that differ the center of mask in black.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#define WIDTH  16
#define HEIGHT 16

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat image(HEIGHT, WIDTH, CV_8UC1);
    Mat imageFinal(HEIGHT, WIDTH, CV_8UC1);

    int values[WIDTH][HEIGHT] = {0, 0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 0, 0,
                                 0, 0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 0, 0,
                                 0, 0,   0, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 0, 0,
                                 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 0, 0,
                                 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0,
                                 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0,
                                 0, 0,   0, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0,
                                 0, 0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0, 0, 0,
                                 0, 0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0, 0, 0,
                                 0, 0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0, 0, 0,
                                 0, 0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0, 0, 0,
                                 0, 0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 0, 0,
                                 0, 0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0, 0, 0,
                                 0, 0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0, 0, 0,
                                 0, 0,   0,   0,   0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,   0,   0,   0, 0, 0,
                                 0, 0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0, 0, 0};

    for(int row = 0; row < WIDTH; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < HEIGHT; col++){
            image.data[col + row * image.cols] = values[row][col];
        }
    }

    image.copyTo(imageFinal);

    int count = 0;

    for(int row = 1; row < image.rows-1; row++){
        for(int col = 1; col < image.cols-1; col++){
            count = 0;
            for(int a = -1; a <= 1; a++){
                for(int b = -1; b <= 1; b++){
                    if(image.at<uchar>(row + a, col + b) == 255){
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }cout << count << endl;
            if(count == 9){
                for(int a = -1; a <= 1; a++){
                    for(int b = -1; b <= 1; b++){
                        if(a != 0 && b != 0){
                            imageFinal.at<uchar>(row + a, col + b) = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    imshow("Image", image);
    imshow("final", imageFinal);

    waitKey(0);  
    return 0;
}
```

But the result it's not correct.

[Initial image and correct result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0FyC.jpg)
[Wrong result][1]

Comment: Why I have -1 ? It's not good question ? Or ?

Comment: "But the result it's not correct"... what is "not correct" ? The images are much too small to see any difference

Comment: But what is the correct formula or filter for erosion ?

Comment: I wrote an answer, no guarantee for correctness, but you may give it a try

Comment: You've linked to the same image twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure, but after reading the [wiki entry on erosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erosion_(morphology)) I think a correct implementation would be like this:

```
for each pixel(x,y) in original_image
    count neigbours where original_image == 255
    if count == 9
        new_image(x,y) = 255
    else 
        new_image(x,y) = 0
    end
end
```

while you have

```
for each pixel(x,y) in original_image
    count neigbours where original_image == 255
    if count == 9
        set all neighbours (but not the pixel itself) in new_image to 0
end
```

Basically erosion should do for a 3x3 part of the image...

```
1 1 1         ? ? ?            0 1 1      ? ? ? 
1 1 1    ->   ? 1 ?      and   1 1 1  ->  ? 0 ? 
1 1 1         ? ? ?            1 1 1      ? ? ?
```

but you do

```
1 1 1         0 0 0 
1 1 1    ->   0 1 0
1 1 1         0 0 0
```

When applying the filter you should change only the value of the pixel you are looking at, but you change all the neighbours, but not the pixel itself.

I find the formulas in the wiki article not too enlightening, maybe this helps to understand:

```
new_image(x,y) = (3x3Sub(old_image,x,y) == mask) * 255
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explication :D

Comment: @Laurentiu you are welcome. Even though your problem is solved and you accepted an answer, please consider to improve the question. In its current state it isnt clear what is the problem with the resulting image.